# Is there a standard for writing a command synopsis?

Tags: command-line, man

It appears to me that everyone has their own idea on how to write a *synopsis* describing *command usage* for the end user.

For example, this is the format from `man grep`:

```
grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]
grep [OPTIONS] [-e PATTERN | -f FILE] [FILE...]
```

Now this has some syntax that appears in other manpages.  `[]` is recognized as optional, and `...` makes sense as multiple of the same input.

But people use `|` or `/` for OR and there are others that will reverse what `[]` means. Or they do not give any indication as to where `[OPTIONS]` goes.

I would like to follow a standard for what I write, but every website I look at tells me something different.

Is there an actual *standard* way of writing synopses, or is the convention just what people have been doing over time?

Comment: Pick one and stick with it.

Comment: For some reason I don't think that would help.  Every person would have there own standard, and then nothing would ever get done about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The classic standard for this is from POSIX, [Utility Argument Syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) (thanks to @illuminÉ for the updated link). It describes the syntax to be used in man pages, for example

```
utility_name[-a][-b][-c option_argument]
    [-d|-e][-f[option_argument]][operand...]
```

Being classic, it recommends using single-character options, with `-W` recommended for use by vendors, and that is how multi-character options are accommodated (see, for example, [gcc Option Summary](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html)).

GNU software introduced multi-character options that start with `--`. Some guidelines from GNU for formatting man pages with those options can be found in the [help2man reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/help2man/#--help-recommendations).

Answer (score 1):

Actually one answer can be found looking for `SYNOPSIS` (surprise!) in `man 7 man-pages`; it says:

```text
       SYNOPSIS      A brief summary of the command or function's interface.

                     For commands, this shows the syntax of  the  command  and
                     its  arguments  (including options); boldface is used for
                     as-is text and italics are used to  indicate  replaceable
                     arguments.   Brackets  ([])  surround optional arguments,
                     vertical bars (|) separate choices,  and  ellipses  (...)
                     can  be  repeated.   For functions, it shows any required
                     data declarations or #include directives, followed by the
                     function declaration.

                     Where  a  feature  test macro must be defined in order to
                     obtain the declaration of a function (or a variable) from
                     a header file, then the SYNOPSIS should indicate this, as
                     described in feature_test_macros(7).
```